# Using calculated column within SQL query

Tags: sql

I need help with a subquery. I think I’m close but not quite sure. I want to use a calculated column within another calculation. In the example want to use “numerator” in the calculation of the “denominator”. I’m new to subqueries.

```
SELECT
   sum(case when denominator=1 and  q10=1 then 1 else 0 end) as numerator 
    FROM (
            SELECT sum(case when q5=1 and q6=1 then 1 else 0 end) as denominator 
  FROM datasource
```

| q5 | q6 | q10 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |

I want to calculate a “denominator” column where it’s 1 if q5 and q6 are equal to 1 or else “denominator”=0. Then calculate a “numerator” column if the calculated denominator column is 1 and q10 is 1 then “numerator”=1 or else “numerator”=0. You can ignore the sum command cause I just wanted to sum the columns at the end but for the purpose of the question it isn’t important

Update…
I tried the below query as suggested and get the error “Expression not in GROUP BY key”

```
SELECT sum(case when denominator=1 and q10 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as numerator 
FROM (
    SELECT q10,
           sum(case when q5=1 and q6=1 then 1 else 0 end) as denominator 
     FROM datasource) t
```

Comment: Please post your table structures and some data values.

Comment: I updated the post with table value examples. I want to calculate the denominator based on the table value conditions then the numerator based on the the calculated denominator and another table value.

Comment: That's great, however, the question is still not clear.  To make it better you should provide an example.

Comment: I want to calculate a “denominator” column where it’s 1 if q5 and q6 are equal to 1 or else “denominator”=0. Then calculate a “numerator” column if the calculated denominator column is 1 and q10 is 1 then “numerator”=1 or else “numerator”=0. You can ignore the sum command cause I just wanted to sum the columns at the end but for the purpose of the question it isn’t important.

Comment: There are rules to be followed here.  I am trying to assist you, so that your question does not get deleted.  That should be it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't added the aggregation part, but I think this will get you close to what you are trying to do.

```
SELECT case when denominator=1 and q10 = 1 then 1 else 0 end as numerator 
FROM (
    SELECT q10,
           case when q5=1 and q6=1 then 1 else 0 end as denominator 
     FROM datasource
     GROUP BY q10) t
```

Comment: Thanks. I think that’s getting me closer. I’m getting the error “Expression not in GROUP BY key” now.

Comment: Please post your updated query so I can check what went wrong.

Comment: I updated my post with the new query.

Comment: Your subquery is missing a group by clause. Try the updated query I just posted and see if it gives you the result you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks. It cleared the error and actually ran. It didn’t quite give me the result I was expecting but I think I can figure it out from here.